# RFID reader standards

Tags: rfid, mifare, smartcard-reader, iso-15693

I have an RFID reader which is ISO 14443A compliant. It is capable of reading Mifare 1k (s50), Mifare 4k (s70), and Mifare Mini (s20) cards. I want to know if the same RFID reader can read the cards which are ISO 15693 compliant. I am new with RFID and I dont know anything about the ISO standards.

Answer (score 1):

Compliancy to ISO14443 does not imply compliancy to ISO15693. However, some reader chips can do both. If you can tell the model name of your reader, or the reader chip inside, it may be possible to tell whether it supports ISO15693.

Answer (score 1):

Check with your reader manufacturer to see if it supports both protocols. Many do; but, you should double check to be sure.

Even if it does support both, it will likely NOT be able to do so simultaneously. Likely, you will have to toggle between the two protocols in order work with both types of RFID tags.

Answer (score 1):

ISO14443 A/B and ISO15693 standard operate on the same frequency 13.56 MHz, and both have about the same read range when reading tags 5 - 20 cm, but from then on the similarities end.
They have different ways to access RFID tags and perform inventory, data read/write and different memory organization.
Because of the similarities some manufacturers provide readers that can handle both types of tags, but the procedure is different due to the different standards (so a software designed to read ISO14443 will not read ISO15693 and vice-versa).
As previous answers you will need to check with your manufacturer to be sure, but if you need a recommendation of reader with which I have worked you can try the IDTronic Desktop EVO HF or IDTronic Desktop EVO LEGIC. From my knowledge it's under 100 $.
Datasheet here:
[Desktop EVO Reader Datasheet](http://idtronic-rfid.com/pdfs/05_USB%20Readers/USB%20Desktop%20Reader%20EVO%20-%20EN.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

the  RFID reader  ISO 14443A can not read the cards which are ISO 15693.

they are totally two different kind standard.

for rfid reader, i think you could first learn from this rfid news here http://syncotek.com/news/